# can anyone guide How to set search button

Tags: android, android-listview, imageview

I'm developing an app of wallpapers. In it I have more than 100 images. I'm using 2 buttons to change an image to the next one and backward. Now I want to use a third button which will open the complete list of the names of drawable images and this list should move up and down. If I select the desired image name then it should open that image.
This list also has 2 buttons on top of it, one to go to the image and one to cancel. Here is what it would look like:
[image]

Here is my XML layout.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="fill" 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:weightSum="100" >
  <ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/idImageViewPic"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp" 
    android:layout_weight="100"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
    android:background="#66FFFFFF" 
    android:maxHeight="91dip" 
    android:maxWidth="47dip"
    android:padding="10dip" 
    android:src="@drawable/r0" /> 
 <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
 <Button 
     android:id="@+id/bprev"
     android:layout_width="0dp" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:text="Back" >
     </Button> 
 <Button
      android:id="@+id/bnext"
      android:layout_width="0dp" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:text="Next" > 
      </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

My Main Activity:

```
 public class Main extends Activity {
  private ImageView hImageViewPic;
  private Button iButton, gButton;
  private int currentImage = 0;
   int[] images = { R.drawable.r1, R.drawable.r2, R.drawable.r3, R.drawable.r4, R.drawable.r5, R.drawable.r6, R.drawable.r7, R.drawable.r8, R.drawable.r9, R.drawable.r10 }; 
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
     hImageViewPic = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.idImageViewPic); 
     iButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bnext);
     gButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bprev); 
   //Just set one Click listener for the image
     iButton.setOnClickListener(iButtonChangeImageListener); 
     gButton.setOnClickListener(gButtonChangeImageListener);
    } 
     View.OnClickListener iButtonChangeImageListener = new OnClickListener() { 
     public void onClick(View v) {
   //Increase Counter to move to next Image 
     currentImage++; 
     currentImage = currentImage % images.length; 
    hImageViewPic.setImageResource(images[currentImage]);
    }
    }; 
     View.OnClickListener gButtonChangeImageListener = new OnClickListener() { 
       public void onClick(View v) {
    //Increase Counter to move to next Image
      currentImage--;
      currentImage = currentImage % images.length; 
    hImageViewPic.setImageResource(images[currentImage]); 
   }
  };}
```

If I use another button in XML then what should I write in the Main Activity? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

i think , what you can do is :

you have list of drawables/bitmaps device .

```
Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yourImage); // Drawables
Bitmap myLogo = ((BitmapDrawable) myDrawable).getBitmap();
imageView.setImageBitmap(myLogo);
```

if images is selected from device , or you have paths :

```
Uri selectedImage = convert your image path into URI ;
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
userImg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

**Edited :**

At last , but before this line ,

```
ImageViewPic.setImageResource(images[currentImage]) ;
```

Add this line :

```
Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yourImage); // Drawables
Bitmap currentImage= ((BitmapDrawable) myDrawable).getBitmap();
```

then add

```
ImageViewPic.setImageResource(images[currentImage]) ;
```

Comment: Thanx to reply sir. How can I use it in my main activity. Can you plz edit my main activity.

Comment: See the Edited Section , I am not a Sir , i am just a small contributer of stackoverFlow .